# SPI for localization in Java

Tags: java, locale, spi

Regarding the SPI package (service provider interface) of the locales. 
Directly from this [oracle java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/services.html):

> These methods first check whether the Java runtime environment
>   supports the requested locale; if so, they use that support.
>   Otherwise, the methods call the getAvailableLocales() methods of
>   installed providers for the appropriate interface to find a provider
>   that supports the requested locale.

Once I create a spi interface and implement it by overriding all the methods needed to, How can I *install* that class in order to make that class seen at run time?

Thanks in advance.